# Has the abc conjuncture been proved by Shinichi Mochizuki?

Tags: proof-verification

I'd like to know is his proof was reviewed, and what exactly happened.

Comment: It is a duplicate, but it is possible there is new information on the subject.

Comment: ... which should be added to the original question.

Comment: @Thursday:  that would be nice, but I'll bet it won't be-the question won't be on the radar of somebody who knows (unless s/he sees this one)

Comment: @RossMillikan, Mochizuki still does not travel to other universities to present his work. A friend of his has organized a big conference in November.

Comment: Hmmm. Go Yamashita really is giving a series of lectures at Kyushu right now, but it is just a part of the overall picture.